# Laravel Homestead Redis Port Forwarding

Tags: php, laravel, redis, vagrant, homestead

I'm having some trouble here trying to remotely connect to my local Homestead Redis server. I'm using both commandline (redis-cli) and [RDM](http://redisdesktop.com/).

I'm able to connect with Postgresql with PgAdmin in this box, but Redis returns with:

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:63790: Connection refused

My Redis config file "bind" directive is commented, so it should accept connections from all sources. I also tried to stop Redis and start it again, manually pointing to the config file, but without success.

In my Homestead.yaml config file, Redis port was not forwarded by default. According to Homestead's [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#ports), I can set port forwarding like this:

```
ports:
    - send: 63790
      to: 6379
      protocol: udp
```

Well, I also tried that and restarted the server, but it didn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need port forwarding to be able to connect to Redis server on homestead.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For Homestead 0.4 above. Due to redis security setting, it bind only for 127.0.0.1

In this case, you need to bind extra IP address.

1. SSH to you server.

`$sudo vi /etc/redis/redis.conf`

Scroll to the line `bind 127.0.0.1`
add extra IP address 192.168.10.10, it will look like this

`bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.10.10`

save and exit.

2. Restart redis server and exit your server.

`$sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart`

That's all, you should be able connect to your Homestead redis from your host.

Comment: Awesome Stuff!!

Comment: I found that instead of using 192.168.10.10, you now need to use the IP address specified in your /etc/hosts file, instead of the IP address specified in your Homestead.yaml file. For me that IP address was 10.211.55.5.

Comment: With the new Laravel Homestead 9.0.1 This problem arose. Following these steps in Laravel Homestead did the trick ... but I don't know why the email verification started to send lots of emails to my email trap account :/

Comment: You're a live-saver! I was looking for the /etc/redis/redis.conf file on my computer, instead of in the vagrant installation. Suddenly dawned on me, after reading your answer, that I was making that mistake. Now my cache works and clears ;)

Answer (score 7):

SSH to the machine and open `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Find line which starts with `bind` directive, comment it out and save the file. 
Then restart redis-server with `sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart`.

Thanks to that Redis will listen for all connections from all available interfaces. You don't need any extra port forwarding.

Comment: This worked for me (windows 10, homestead v5) but I also had to set `protected-mode no` too.

Answer (score 3):

Remove ports settings from your `Homestead.yaml` you won't need it.

Now by default redis in homestead vm is listening on its normal port, 6379.

You can ssh into your vm and check it:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ps -aux | grep redis
redis      996  0.1  0.4  35232  8752 ?        Ssl  01:53   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

To connect to the vm's redis instance from your local machine you need to use an IP address that is specified in your `Homestead.yaml`. By default it is `192.168.10.10`:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.10.10
```

If you have domain name set up in your local `/etc/hosts` for your app you can use it instead:

```
redis-cli -h homestead.app
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I just opened a [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/1670) in Laravel's docs to add your instructions to connect to Redis.

Comment: I don't think this is the case anymore with the latest homestead VM -- it seems that redis only listens on 127.0.0.1 now.  So, back to port forwarding it is.

Answer (score 1):

1. SSH to your server.

   $sudo vi /etc/redis/redis.conf

Scroll to the line `bind 127.0.0.1 and change to 0.0.0.0`, it will look like this

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

save and exit.

2. Restart redis server and exit your server.

   $sudo service redis-server restart

That's all, you should be able connect to your Homestead redis from your host.

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.10.10
```